# Bad quality of image via Glide

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap, android-glide

I need to download image from url and then place it as background of my RelativeLayout.
The image (jpeg) size is about 10kb and it has good quality and resolution. But when I try to download the image with Glide it looks compressed (see background image on the screen below).

[image]

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load("url...")
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(rootViewWidth, rootViewHeight) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
                    rootView.setBackground(drawable);
                }
            });
```

How can I improve that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 0):

Glide default Bitmap Format is set to RGB_565 since it consumed just 50% memory footprint But picaso's Bitmap Format is ARGB_8888..

you can switch Bitmap Format to ARGB_8888 by creating a new class which extended from GlideModule like this:

```
public class GlideConfiguration implements GlideModule {
@Override
public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    // Apply options to the builder here.
    builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
}
@Override
public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    // register ModelLoaders here.
}
```

}

And then define it as meta-data inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.glidepicasso.GlideConfiguration"
        android:value="GlideModule"/>
```

It looks far better now!

All the best :)

[if u have any doubt please refer this Article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)